# comparison of String and Integer using compareTo and instanceOf

Tags: java, string, compareto

I have a code snippet which I am not able to understand what exactly it does..
This code is in JavaBean..

```
private Object myNumb;

//then getter and setter for this

public int compareTo(myRptObj o){

        if (myNumb instanceof String && o.myNumb instanceof Integer) {
          return_value =  1;
        } else if (myNumb instanceof Integer && o.myNumb instanceof String) {
          return_value = -1;
        } else if (myNumb instanceof String && o.myNumb instanceof String) {
          return_value = ((String) myNumb).compareTo((String)o.myNumb);
        } else if (myNumb instanceof Integer && o.myNumb instanceof Integer) {
          return_value = ((Integer) myNumb).compareTo((Integer)o.myNumb);
        }

}
```

I want to understand `compareTo` and how the comparison for String and Integer is done?
`myNumb` can be of type `Integer` or `String`.

Comment: 6 questions, none accepted, no votes ... how do you think are you motivating people around here to help?

Answer (score 1):

The snippet makes sure that **any** `Integer` compares less than **any** `String`.

`Integer`-`Integer` and `String`-`String` comparisons are done the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

the first two if clauses ensure that Strings are considered greater than integers. The second two if clauses delegate the comparison between Strings and between Integers to the `compareTo()` implementation of these classes so that they are ordered as usual.

Note that it is *very, very bad design* to have this kind of code where a variable can be "of type X or Y" - exactly because it forces you to write code like this.

Instead, decide on one type and convert to/from that type where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> ... what exactly it does.

Basically: strings are greater than integers, if both are the same type use their natural ordering (either compare 2 strings or 2 integers).

Answer (score 0):

Since **myNumb** can be either a **String** or an **Integer**, **compareTo** is checking what types they are first. If they are not the same type (one is an **Integer** and one is a **String**) they are not equal and therefore returns 1 or -1 as appropriate. If they are of the same type, it is casting them to that type and delegating to that type's compareTo.